# unsupervised pattern discovery - methods?

Tags: time-series, data-mining

Given that I select features manually, what methods are available for pattern discovery with the purpose of time series prediction (footnote)?

I only [stumbled](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16057/scan-for-chart-patterns-software) upon hierarchical clustring ("bottom-up") and proprietary sofftware. [This post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30996/data-mining-of-financial-time-series-and-pattern-discovery-beyond-technical-an) says there are a lot such methods.

Footnote: prediction in wider sense is meant. The outcome to predict is chosen manually, too, from the trivial "color of the next candle stick" via "wiskers will be longer than the body" to "next day will set a higher high", just anything, you name it

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few:

- K-means
- PCA
- HMM (learned with expectation-maximization or Viterbi algorithm)
- Autoencoders
- Outlier detection, e.g. Chauvenet's criterion

Comment: picking KNN as example because of its simplicity (distance measures aside..), how's prediction happening AND how are patterns discovered?

Comment: Strictly speaking, KNN is supervised because you give it training examples. You can set it up so that it's not trained against the actual labels you are trying to predict.